# Use TeX fonts by default even if stix fonts are installed

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

At my school pc, they have stix fonts installed. Mathjax by default uses stix fonts if they are installed. The problem is, they look really ugly imho:

Here is an screen shot of the stix font:
http://snag.gy/mz3vk.jpg

And here a screenshot of the TeX fonts which are used if stix is not installed: http://snag.gy/iQZ1f.jpg

I think that most people prefer the tex like fonts above the stix font. Just because people are used to those computer modern roman like fonts in latex. It is really easy to tell mathjax to use TeX fonts by default, even if stix fonts are installed. You only need to edit this code `availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"]` to this code `availableFonts: ["TeX"]`.

Comment: Where does that code fragment appear?

Comment: @AntonioVargas [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412878/approximate-int-u-0b-e-fracu2-acaudu/538315#538315).

Comment: I used ctrl+F to try to find the world `availableFonts` in the source code for that answer but it doesn't seem to be there.  Could you be more specific?

Comment: @AntonioVargas If I check the source of math.stackexchange.com then this code appears at line 32. You should be able to find it with crt+f I think.

Comment: Who downvoted and why ?

Comment: I, because I disagree. I consciously use STIX because it uniformises the rendering of TeX over the several browsers I use.

Comment: I misunderstood -- I thought there was a piece of code that I, personally, could change to obtain what you want.  To clarify, are you asking StackExchange to modify their own html code as per your suggestion?

Comment: @Lord_Farin I don't understand. Are you saying that with STIX fonts installed all browser look the same, and without stix fonts installed, some browsers look different ? For me, without stix fonts installed, mathjax looks exactly the same in IE10,chrome,firefox or opera.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Yes, I'm asking StackExchange to modify their own code.

Comment: I also downvoted, for almost the same reason as @Lord_Farin. I don't use the STIX fonts, and I dislike them. But I do feel that there is a point to using local fonts over webfonts. This is even more the case with the release of MJ 2.3 which added several other webfonts.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What is the the point of using local fonts over webfonts ? Is this because it loads faster ?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I've been experimenting a bit. After I installed the STIX fonts locally, all the math is in a STIX font at MSE. After that I installed the mathjax fonts locally from here: http://www.mathjax.org/download/. It seems like that if both STIX and TeX fonts are installed locally, stackexchange prefers the local TeX font above the local STIX font. So for people that are intrested in installing the font locally, you could also choose installing the TeX font locally.

Comment: I will ask if my university can install those fonts as well, then my issue would be solved.

Comment: @Kasper Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. And I probably wouldn't have bothered if the rendering in Firefox (or Chrome, can't remember) wasn't so ugly (at least when I made this choice, one or two years back).

Comment: @Lord_Farin I think that maybe 2 years ago some browsers didn't support webfonts. For browsers that don't support webfonts, mathjax uses really ugly imagefonts if there is no local math font available. New version of firefox/chrome/IE/opera support webfonts now.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I think your eyes would appreciate it, if you install a local version of the TeX fonts ;)